# How to use Boost C++ Libraries on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, boost

I am trying to use Boost Libraries on MacOS.

I installed boost using `brew install boost`. This installed boost in `usr/local/Cellar/boost`.

I compiled 2 programs with the same command `g++ --std=c++11 main.cpp -o main` and then `./main`

However the first one compiled successfully while the second one doesn't. What should I do?

Program1.

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

    std::for_each(
        in(std::cin), in(), std::cout << (_1 * 3) << " " );
}
```

Program2.

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

int add( int i, int j ) { return i+j; }

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( my_test )
{
    BOOST_CHECK( add( 2,2 ) == 4 );       

    BOOST_REQUIRE( add( 2,2 ) == 4 );     

    if( add( 2,2 ) != 4 )
      BOOST_ERROR( "Ouch..." );      

    if( add( 2,2 ) != 4 )
      BOOST_FAIL( "Ouch..." );           

    if( add( 2,2 ) != 4 ) throw "Ouch..."; 

    BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE( add( 2,2 ) == 4, 
                         "add(..) result: " << add( 2,2 ) );

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL( add( 2,2 ), 4 );  
}
```

I get the following error when I compile program 2.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::test_tools::tt_detail::report_assertion(boost::test_tools::assertion_result const&, boost::unit_test::lazy_ostream const&, boost::unit_test::basic_cstr
ing<char const>, unsigned long, boost::test_tools::tt_detail::tool_level, boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_type, unsigned long, ...)", referenced from:
      my_test::test_method() in del-9b4dcb.o

      bool boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_frwd<boost::test_tools::tt_detail::equal_impl_frwd, int, int>(boost::test_tools::tt_detail::equal_impl_frwd, boost
::unit_test::lazy_ostream const&, boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, unsigned long, boost::test_tools::tt_detail::tool_level, boost::test_tools::tt_det
ail::check_type, int const&, char const*, int const&, char const*) in del-9b4dcb.o
  "boost::unit_test::unit_test_log_t::set_checkpoint(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, unsigned long, boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>)", r
eferenced from:
      my_test_invoker() in del-9b4dcb.o
      my_test::test_method() in del-9b4dcb.o
  "boost::unit_test::test_case::test_case(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, unsigned long, boost::functio
n<void ()> const&)", referenced from:
      boost::unit_test::make_test_case(boost::function<void ()> const&, boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>,
 unsigned long) in del-9b4dcb.o
  "boost::unit_test::ut_detail::auto_test_unit_registrar::auto_test_unit_registrar(boost::unit_test::test_case*, boost::unit_test::decorator::collector&, unsigne
d long)", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init.1 in del-9b4dcb.o
  "boost::unit_test::ut_detail::normalize_test_case_name(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>)", referenced from:
      boost::unit_test::make_test_case(boost::function<void ()> const&, boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>,
 unsigned long) in del-9b4dcb.o
  "vtable for boost::unit_test::unit_test_log_t", referenced from:
      boost::unit_test::unit_test_log_t::unit_test_log_t() in del-9b4dcb.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You need to include headers with -I/usr/local/include and link (if needed) with -L/usr/local/lib. Possibly with a -lboost_foo_bar.

Comment: @kometen `g++ main.cpp -o main -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib -l boost-test` does not work. It gives an error `ld: library not found for -lboost-test`

Comment: You don't need space between -I and /usr... and -L and /usr.... You may need to use -lboost_unit_test_framework.a. Do a "ls -l /usr/local/lib/libboost_*test*" to see the name of the library.

Comment: I am using `g++  main.cpp -o main -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib/ -libboost_test_exec_monitor.a` now. Still shows me the same error.:(

Comment: Using the -l (lowercase l) you don't need to prepend lib in libboost_foo_bar.a. So the syntax is -lboost_foo_bar.a.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [boost's documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/test_cases/test_organization_nullary.html#ref_BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE) you may want to try the following include statement.

```
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
```

Answer (score 1):

Linker errors happen when the compiler fails to find required library binaries. You need to specify the path to the **boost test** library. The thing is where your boost libraries are - probably not `/usr/local/lib`, but `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/.../lib` on Mac.

So use something like

```
g++ -L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/.../lib main.cpp -o main -lboost_unit_test_framework
```